# How to bind JQUERY Data Table with JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to bind jquery data table for that I am using ASMX web services which is returning JSON data.

**Problem**

Just for testing purpose i make my web method as **parameter less** method then Everything is correct data is also populating, able to fill in `Data table` Without any issues and also if I **hard coded parameters value on server side** its filtering the data and binding from `Data Table`

But if I passing parameter value from Clint side even- though  i can see value on server side on this situation data is not rendering on table I am getting empty table

Its really surprising for me

Just for testing purpose I make my web method as parameter less then `Table` is binding with `DataTable` properly

**Returning JSON Data**

[image]

**AJAX**

```
function LoadTableData() {
        var params = {
            UserName: $('#txtUserName').val(), UserID: $('#txtUserID').val(),
            Status: $('input[name="Status"]:checked').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'UserService.asmx/Get_Data',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    data: JSON.parse(data.d),
                    columns: [
                        {
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                            }
                        },
                        { 'data': 'Status', class: 'editable text' },
                        { 'data': 'USER_LOGIN', class: 'editable text' },
                        { 'data': 'USER_NAME', class: 'editable text' },
                        {
                            //edit button creation    
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return createButton('edit', row.id);
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            //delete button creation    
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return createButton('delete', row.id);
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',

                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
                    ],
                    "searching": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "No data available"
                    },
                    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                        $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
                        return nRow;
                    },
                })
                function createButton(buttonType, rowID) {
                    var buttonText = buttonType == "edit" ? "Edit" : "Delete";
                    
                    return "<a href='#my_modal' data-toggle='modal' class='open-AddBookDialog' data-book-id='my_id_value'><img src='Images/edit.png' height='20' width='20'></a>"
                }
            },
            
        });
```

**Table structure**

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>S.No</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         <th>USER_LOGIN</th>
         <th>USER_NAME</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

**Server Side Method**

```
[WebMethod]
    public void Get_Data(string UserName, string UserID, string Status)
    {
        string UserIDModify = "";
        string UserNameModify = "";
        string PasswordModify = "";
        int StatusModify;
        if (UserID != "")
            UserIDModify = UserID;
        else
            UserIDModify = "%";
        if (UserName != "")
            UserNameModify = UserName;
        else
            UserNameModify = "%";
        PasswordModify = "%";
        if (Status.ToString() == ("Active"))
            StatusModify = 1;
        else
            if (Status.ToString() == ("Inactive"))
            StatusModify = 0;
        else
            StatusModify = 0;

        DataTable dt_MobileUserLogin = FAV_VS_BLL.Search_MobileUserLogin(UserNameModify, UserIDModify, PasswordModify, StatusModify);
        List<MobileUserMaster> list = new List<MobileUserMaster>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt_MobileUserLogin.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new MobileUserMaster
            {
                USER_LOGIN = dr["USER_LOGIN"].ToString(),
                USER_NAME = dr["USER_NAME"].ToString(),
                Status = dr["status"].ToString(),
                PASSWORD = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString()
            });
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(list));
       
    }
```

Since My JSON is not in correct format so I am not able to bind table

```
{
"d": null
}
```

Why data is not filling in `datatable` and its not populating any thing on my table
Can any one help me on same where I am doing mistake

Comment: forgot to add `[WebMethod]` attribute ?

Comment: I notice that your asmx method has 3 arguments (UserName, UserID, Status) but the parameter var in ajax call just has 2 elements (UserID is missing). Try to add missing parameter to your ajax call

Comment: @Vermicello I have also passing `Status` check once again

Comment: @Shree i ahve decorated with  `[WebMethod]` attribute but no changes

Comment: Console error ?

Comment: Also check URL path?

Comment: @Shree No console error nothing i am getting on now i can able to return JSON data but datable not filling

Comment: in `OnSuccessFunctionalPasswordCall` you are referring to some `d` that is not defined anywhere

Comment: @FlashThunder Sorry my bad i Posted wrong Ajax Method kindly check my updated Code Please

Comment: @ak74 maybe it's because of `data: JSON.parse(data.d),` instead of `data: JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: @FlashThunder tried as you suggested but no changes

Comment: Long time ago I used Datatable but didn't datable need a response containing more information then only the list of data? I think there was a well defined format of json you have to return which also contains attributes like number of Total and Filtered elements etc?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Could you please suggest how i can return  `attributes like number of Total and Filtered elements` I am shucking this problem from last one week but no sucess